# PWM resolution in pic 16F877

Tags: pic, mikroc, pwm

Here I'm using pic 16f877 MCU and mikroc for pic compiler to understand PWM signals.
The data sheet says that this MCU is having a 10 bit resolution in PWM. I cant understand what this resolution means. Does it mean that if I use it to power a motor I can get 1024 different speeds.
Here is a program I wrote in mikroc to gradully increase the light of a LED and again decrease it.

```
int i=0;

void blink_up(){
  i++;
  PWM1_Set_Duty(i);
  Delay_ms(10);
}

void blink_down(){
  i--;
  PWM1_Set_Duty(i);
  Delay_ms(10);
}


void main() {
  trisc=0;
  portc=0;

  PWM1_Init(5000); //initilize PWM 1 at 5kHz
  PWM1_Start();
  PWM1_Set_Duty(i);

 while(1){
    while(i != 1023){
     blink_up();
    }

    while(i!=0) {
     blink_down();
  }

}
```

But this wont give the expected results. The LED gradully bilnks up and suddenly switch off and again gradually blinks up. But when I change the line `while(i != 1023)` to `while(i != 255)` it gives the expected results.

So I want to know what the 10 bit resolution means, did I understand it wrong or am I doing anything wrong.

please help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I got the solution. I'll give it because it may be helpful to somebody else.

The mikroc's pwm library don't support 10 bits. So `PWM1_Set_Duty()` accepts only a number from 0 to 255. That's 0% duty to 100% duty cycle. If you want to use 10 bit resolution you should do it manually writing for registers.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.  :)  Glad you were able to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have successfully managed to get your code working, try using the internal PIC registers. A resolution of 10 bits is way more powerful for, let's say, RGB led's than 8bit. It's not that hard to get it to work by yourself, it's written directly in the datasheet and there's a lot of website granting you with functions for calculating the duty cycle and the frequency of your PWM module.

The datasheet for CCP (PWM) mode from MicroChip: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/31014a.pdf